# javascript get only div parent node value(without child nodes)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my problem:

```
<html>
    <div id="parentdiv">
        some parent value
        <div id="childdiv">some child value</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

> parent div --> parent div content --> child div --> child div content --> end child div --> end parent div

I need to acquire only parent div value, without child div value. How can I do that in Javascript?

Comment: The situation is not clear. Can you better explain it / provide code example please?

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks" in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: In other words you need to get `some parent value` string.

Comment: Fixed.Thanks for fast response.
dfsq - YES

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2007276/1718121) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
alert($('#parentdiv').clone().children().remove().end().text());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML - just wrap the value in a `<p>` tag (as it should be) and then access it like so..

HTML

```
<html>
    <div id="parentdiv">
        <p>some parent value</p>
        <div id="childdiv">some child value</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
$('#parentdiv p').text();
```

If there are other `<p>` elements in the parentdiv then use a class.

Comment: Uh.Sorry i've answered in wrong topic lol.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007215/jquery-get-tag-content-excluding-nested-tags/15068321#15068321 - here is solution to this problem.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var $parent = $('#parentdiv').clone();

$parent.find('#childdiv').remove();

var parentvalue = $parent.text();
```

Try it in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/QFaWR/)

Answer (score 0):

just wrap it inside a span tag and get the inneHTML of that tag